# Magento: Payflow Pro Using PaypalUK Module?

Tags: magento, paypal, payflowpro

I'm working on implementing PayPal Payflow Pro (technically "Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition") for a client's Magento store, and I noticed that it is running through the PaypalUk module rather than the Paypal module. Judging from the name, it sounds like the PaypalUk module is for Paypal in the United Kingdom. Is this incorrect? Does anybody know what the basis for the module name is?

The Paypal module system.xml points explicitly to the PaypalUk module:

```
<wpp_pe translate="label comment">
    <label>Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition (includes Express Checkout)</label>
    ...
    <config_path>payment/paypaluk_direct/active</config_path>
    ...
</wpp_pe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition *was* a product available solely to the United Kingdom. Also, your 'PARTNER' value will likely be 'PayPalUK' as well.
So yes, this is correct.